# SQL server secondary logfile staying in status 2

Tags: sql-server, logfiles

I recently started at a new company and inherited a database that is being heavily replciated that has two log files.

The 2nd log file holds around 1700 VLF's, i am trying to get rid of the 2nd log files ,but it seems that there are status 2 VLF sitting there which i am not able to get rid off.

I have backuped up the log several times and ensured the primary log files has enough room so that the secondary log file is not required for use, without any luck. I am thinking of running a checkpoint after business hours to see if it helps. i have also checked opentran and there are no transactions older than 2 minutes.

Any help would be really usefull as I want to reduce the VLF's as a first step of the replication.

Thanks
Hendo

Comment: There's a database administration tag that you might do better with.  Or better,  http://dba.stackexchange.com/